# a,b = b,a in python vs std::swap() in C++

Tags: python, c++

I know that `a,b = b,a` is basically assigning a tuple `(a,b)` the values of another tuple `(b,a)`. This is, essentially, swapping the values form `a` to `b` and from `b` to `a`. Thus, causing a "swap".

This is the functionality of the `swap()` function in C++.

From research, I have seen that C++'s `swap()` function uses a third temporary variable to perform the swap. I haven't been able to find how is `a,b = b,a` implemented in python.

**How is `a,b = b,a` implemented?**

**Does python also use a third temporary variable? If it doesn't, how does it work?**

**How do both operations compare in terms of speed?** I'm guessing that if python also uses a third variable, the difference in execution time would be due to python being interpreted.

**Edit:** All answers are great, but the community seems to think that Sapan's is the best one. Also thanks to a_guest, whom, although didn't post an answer, gave us a great deal of information in the comments. Also: everyone seems to agree that `swap()` is faster just because its C++. I don't necessarily agree with that. Python can be very fast if run as a frozen binary.

Comment: As you mentioned, the "temporary" variable is the tuple that you create. Also note that `b, a =` is actually referred to as [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Comment: @a_guest That seems a decent answer. Would you like to make one?

Comment: It exists in C++: [`std::tie(a, b) = std::tuple{b, a};`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91a5d9d52b25678f). But `swap`ing is highly preferable.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'd make one if it addressed all the aspects of the OP but I haven't checked (compared) the performance aspect. Though it might be difficult to get reliable results here since other aspects might dominate the swapping time.

Comment: @a_guest I see. Very correct of you, my respect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For tuple assignments, Python uses the stack structure directly:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def abc(a, b):
...     a, b = b, a
... 
>>> dis.dis(abc)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 ROT_TWO             
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

In python, assignments in a target list on the left-hand side are done from left to right.

Comment: Very interesting, so no tuple is being created here, i.e. the swapping is optimized in that sense. Compare with `def foo(a, b): c = b, a; a, b = c` which creates an additional tuple. Also CPython seems to make use of that optimization only for up to three values (e.g. `a, b, c = c, b, a`). Using `def bar(a, b, c, d): a, b, c, d = d, c, b, a` reveals that an intermediate tuple is being created.

Answer (score 10):

> How is a,b = b,a implemented?

First, `b, a` creates a tuple. You can verify this using e.g.

```
>>> tmp = 1, 2
>>> tmp
(1, 2)
```

Then, the assignment uses sequence unpacking, overwriting the names a, b. Hence the code is basically

```
>>> tmp = (a, b)
>>> b, a = tmp
```

> How do both operations compare in terms of speed?

This would depend on your implementation of python. If you use CPython (the standard version), then C++ would likely be much faster since it is compiled and optimized.

## CPython implementation details

In CPython, the swap is sometimes optimized. For small swaps (<4 elements) it uses an optimized swap

```
>>> def swap(a, b):
>>>     a, b = b, a
>>> dis.dis(swap)
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 ROT_TWO
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>> def swap(a, b, c):
>>>     a, b, c = c, b, a
>>> dis.dis(swap)
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 ROT_THREE
             10 ROT_TWO
             11 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             14 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             17 STORE_FAST               2 (c)
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

For swaps of 4 or more elements it does exactly what I wrote above, without optimization.

```
>>> def swap(a, b, c, d):
>>>     a, b, c, d = d, c, b, a
>>> dis.dis(swap)
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                3 (d)
              3 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              4
             15 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          4
             18 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             21 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             24 STORE_FAST               2 (c)
             27 STORE_FAST               3 (d)
             30 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             33 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Much more insightful now :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help in improving the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Sapan's answer:

In C++ it might conceptionally use a third variable to swap. But you can see here that the compiler can produce the same assembly as the one shown from python:

```
void foo(int& a, int& b)
{
    std::swap(a, b);
}
```

turns into

```
foo(int&, int&):
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rsi]
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], edx
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
    ret
```

https://godbolt.org/g/dRrzg6

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly answer about implementation of python but important background about `std::swap`.

C++ `std::swap` will not simple swap two variables using third one. It will use knowledge of internal state to speed it up.

Some example for `std::array` and `std::vector`:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MERLGZ

In both cases it will not use third variable to copy whole object but will directly swap internal representation of both types.

In case of `array` we have branch for case if array have correct alignment or not.
If yes then will swap whole object using two `xmm` registers, if not it will swap each element separately.

In case of `vector` we swap internal pointers between two objects.

Another important thing for `std::swap` is `std::move`, this is C++11 addition that allow to easy swap two variables that normally can't be copied like `std::unique_ptr`.

Right now generic version of `std::swap` look like:

```
template<typename Tp>
inline void swap(Tp& a, Tp& b)
{
    Tp tmp = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

If your type need memory allocation for coping and it support move then no memory allocation will be done there.

Probably most of this things that C++ do, do not apply to how python handle its objects.